# Добавить метку syncfusion

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, создание-метки

По моему, стоит добавить метку [syncfusion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syncfusion), так как есть уже [несколько вопросов об этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=syncfusion). На англоязычном сайте она также **есть**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавлена метка [syncfusion](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syncfusion)